# Can't make custom validations in MVC3 work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have a model called `Proyecto` created by database first method.  To add the annotations for the model I created a new class type partial where I set the annotations but it doesn't work only the `custom one`.  Here's how I tried to achieve this:

**First one**

In this one I set the Interface to the class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Proyecto.MetaData))]
public partial class Proyecto : IValidatableObject
{
    private class MetaData 
    {
        [Display(Name = "Fecha de Solicitud")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaSolicitud { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Debe ingresar a un encargado de la información para el proyecto")]
        [Display(Name="Responsable de la Informacion")]
        public string ResponsableInformacion { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Cliente Nuevo")]
        public Nullable<bool> ClienteNuevo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Debe colocar una explicación que describa la aplicacion a desarrollar")]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Debe Seleccionar un tipo de requerimiento")]
        public Nullable<byte> IdTipoRequerimiento { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Nombre del Cliente")]
        public string NombreCliente { get; set; }

    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if ((ClienteNuevo == true) && (NombreCliente == String.Empty))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Debe Colocar un nombre al Cliente");
        }
    }

}
```

**Second one**
I tried to implement the interface in the metadata class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Proyecto.MetaData))]
public partial class Proyecto 
{
    private class MetaData : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Display(Name = "Fecha de Solicitud")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaSolicitud { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Debe ingresar a un encargado de la información para el proyecto")]
        [Display(Name="Responsable de la Informacion")]
        public string ResponsableInformacion { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Cliente Nuevo")]
        public Nullable<bool> ClienteNuevo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Debe colocar una explicación que describa la aplicacion a desarrollar")]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Debe Seleccionar un tipo de requerimiento")]
        public Nullable<byte> IdTipoRequerimiento { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Nombre del Cliente")]
        public string NombreCliente { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if ((ClienteNuevo == true) && (NombreCliente == String.Empty))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Debe Colocar un nombre al Cliente");
            }
         }

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong???

**UPDATE**

I tried modifying the access modifier of the metadata class to public and only with the name of the class but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I have this for my MVC3 project and it does validation well.

```
    [PropertiesMustMatch("NewPassword", "ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
    public class ChangePasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ValidatePasswordLength]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Confirm new password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Probably you can try replace this code

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Proyecto.MetaData))]
public partial class Proyecto 
{
    private class MetaData : IValidatableObject
    {
```

to another one

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProyectoMetaData))]
public partial class Proyecto 
{
    class ProyectoMetaData
    {
```

Comment: Sorry but I tried modifying the modifier access to `public`, without it like in your example and still without work... =(

Comment: Well... Then create an empty MVC3 project and investigate things you need.